# Custom tab bars, table views, etc

Tags: iphone, objective-c, artwork

this is my first question here at Stack Overflow.

I've been looking for a way to do this ever since I started programming for iOS (which was really not that long ago, about a month) but I haven't been able to find any concrete explanation, so I decided to ask you.

I've seen many apps that have custom artwork in them (e.g. wooden textures, backgrounds with noise, custom table view cells, etc.) and I would like to add some to my own apps, are there any properties that I can access, say for example, on a tab bar?

Check out [Wunderlist](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/wunderlist-task-manager/id406644151?mt=8) or [ReadMore](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/readmore/id353047317?mt=8), these two are great examples of what I mean.

Wunderlist was made using Titanium, obviously editing backgrounds and customizing table view cells and table view backgrounds is easier in JavaScript, but if Titanium has a way of doing it then there must be a way of doing it natively in Objective-C, right?

Thank you in advance, your help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to create a custom UITableView and associated cells.

As a general overview, the Cocoa with Love [Easy custom UITableView drawing](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html) blog post is pretty good and there's also a more recent (and complex) [UITableView construction, drawing and management (revisited)](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/12/uitableview-construction-drawing-and.html) post on the same site if you really want to go for it on the customisation front.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! Not only did you answer my question but the post you pointed me to also helped me understand better how table views work. As a final question to anyone reading this, is there a way to do the same with a navigation bar?

Answer (score 0):

there a few ways of customizing UITabelViewCells.

[Table View Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW1)
Interessting Chapters:

- Programmatically Adding Subviews to a Cell’s Content View
- Loading Custom Table-View Cells From Nib Files
- Subclassing UITableViewCell